# SQL Server select rows from, to

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to select rows in SQL Server 2012, I want to select from row x to row y.

Is there an option in SQL Server to select rows from-to like in mysql limit 10,20?

Comment: [ORDER BY OFFSET and FETCH](http://dbadiaries.com/new-t-sql-features-in-sql-server-2012-offset-and-fetch) are new features in SQL Server 2012 to do exactly that

Comment: Thanks! that should help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `offset`/`fetch` functionality.

The documentation is here.[enter link description here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx)

This is new in SQL Server 2012, so you need other methods in earlier versions of SQL Server, such as using `row_number()` or using nested queries with `top`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
OFFSET 0 ROWS -- Starting Row Number
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY; -- Number of rows you want
```